# Both Apache Shindig and Rave are Retired; What else is available?

Tags: web-applications, opensocial

I'm looking for OpenSocial Container. Apache Shindig and Rave is mentioned in the OpenSocial Home Page [here](https://www.w3.org/blog/2014/12/opensocial-foundation-moves-standards-work-to-w3c-social-web-activity/); but both of those projects are retired. Are there any other Open source alternatives available? I tried my best to search; but except [Gadglet](http://www.gadglet.com/) nothing seems to be related to a OpenSocial Container implementation. Please help me find a OpenSocial container implementation.

I'm basically looking for a specification based container in which I can drop my server-side and client-side modules to get my application running with fair amount of portability, its not a social application really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few months ago since the placement of the Apache Shindig project in the attic, myself together with a few other individuals made an effort to move the Shindig code base under a new Github organization called [OpenDashboards](https://github.com/OpenDashboards).

Although there are plenty of companies out there still using Shindig as a core component in their architectures, the Apache foundation decided the project to be marked as inactive since there was not enough interest from the community regarding new features and pull requests.

My main motivation behind this move was due to the fact that the project was very poorly documented and there was a lack of resources in general.  This is why I have created a [Github project site](http://shindig.opendashboards.org/) along with a ready-to-use Docker image that installs the latest stable version of the Shindig server (v2.5.2).  In the web site you can find instructions on how to download and install.  For gadget development resources have a look at the official [Google Gadgets API](https://developers.google.com/gadgets/) web site.

Keep in mind that even though Shindig development has officially paused from the Apache Foundation project team, Shindig as a solution will still be around for a long time, since no real alternatives exist so far.

The whole concept with the new Github space was to be used as a point of reference from the active Shindig community and help on board new users like yourself through an up-to-date collection of resources, tutorials and show cases.